# Using smarty template (*.tpl) what is {#name#}

Tags: smarty

I am not that familiar with *.tpl and i'm working on a code developed by another person that I can not connect to, however I stumbled across a weird syntax that I can't understand and cant find any answers for it online.

**What is {#word#}?** it's contained in the following code

```
<td align="left" class="questionClas">{#route#|capitalize}</td>
<td align="left" colspan="2">   
 <input type="hidden" name="route_id" id="route_id" readonly />
 <span id="routeac" class="text_normal" style="font-weight:bold"></span>
</td>
```

And that is rendered in HTML:

```
<td align="left" class="questionClas">Route</td>
<td align="left" colspan="2">   
  <input type="hidden" name="route_id" id="route_id" readonly="">
  <span id="routeac" class="text_normal" style="font-weight:bold"></span>
</td>
```

I figured that it displays the text contained within the hashtags but it isn't and seems to be a variable however I cant find that variable in anywhere else in the file.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are [variables loaded from config files](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.config.variables.tpl).